# Construction for pairwise disjoint sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I’ve been reading about measure theory and found that if I have a collection on measurable sets (suppose for the sake of simplicity that they’re intervals here) $\{I_k\}_{k=1}^N$ that there is a way to construct a new countable collection $E_1, E_2 , \dots$ such that $E_i$’s are pairwise disjoint. And that $\bigcup_{i=1}^N I_i = \bigcup_{i=1}^N E_i $.

Now how this works is that first you set $E_1 = I_1$. Then for $i>1$ you define $E_i =I_i \setminus \left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1} I_j \right)$ and this would create a collection for which $\bigcup_{i=1}^N I_i = \bigcup_{i=1}^N E_i  $.

Now I couldn’t find any proof on why this works so I would like to have some insight on what is happening here?

Comment: Have you tried to prove the equality of sets in this case?

Comment: I would first need to prove that this ”algorithm” works? I don’t now beforehand that the rhs of the set equality are pairwise disjoint right?

Comment: Here's a hint: suppose $x\in\bigcup I_i$, then there must be some $i$ such that $x\in I_i$ and $x\notin I_j$ for any $j<i$

Comment: @Georgi The lefthand side is pairwise disjoint by construction of the sets. But there is nothing wrong with proving the result. The $E_i$ are constructed so that every "preceeding" set is taken out of it. Naively the equality holds because you only get "new" elements with every new $I_i$. To show set equality, you have to prove the inclusions $\subseteq$ and $\supseteq$.

Comment: @Vsotvep What would this imply then? It seems that I’ve gotten an $x$ such that I know that for any ”preceeding” sets $x$ isn’t there?

Comment: @Georgi What does this tell you about which $E_k$ this $x$ is in?

Comment: $E_k = I_k \setminus \left(\bigcup_{j < k} I_j\right)$ so it seems that in the first $E_k$ for which $j < k?$

Comment: If $i$ is such that $x\in I_i$ and $x\notin I_j$ for any $j<i$, then $x\in E_i$. In essence, this is how you can show that $\bigcup I_i\subseteq \bigcup E_i$.

Comment: @Cornman I’m wondering how is it that taking the preceeding element out of it results in pairwise disjointness. By this construction $E_1 = I_1$ and say then for $i=2$ I have that $E_2 = I_2 \setminus I_1$. Now in order for $E_1$ and $E_2$ to be pairwise disjoint $E_1 \cap E_2$ must be empty, but $$E_1 \cap E_2 = I_1 \cap (I_2 \setminus I_1) = I_1 \setminus I_2$$?

Comment: @Georgi, I've updated my answer to include disjointness. Your last equation is incorrect: $I_2\setminus I_1$ does not contain any elements from $I_1$, which is exactly what $\setminus$ means. Therefore, $I_1\cap (I_2\setminus I_1)$ cannot contain any elements: such elements need to be both in $I_1$ and not be in $I_1$. If this doesn't convince you, try drawing out the Venn diagrams. If you struggle often with these basic operations on sets, I recommend to review some elementary set theory before tackling measure theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant $N$ to be a natural number, so that we have finitely many intervals $\{I_1,I_2,\dots,I_N\}$, but it also works if we use an infinite set $\{I_1,I_2,\dots\}$. Also, the sets $I_i$ don't need to be intervals, since this is not a necessary assumption in the proof.

We will first show that $\bigcup E_k=\bigcup I_k$ by proving $\bigcup E_k\subseteq \bigcup I_k$ and $\bigcup I_k\subseteq\bigcup E_k$. (Whenever I leave out the sub- and superscripts, such as in the previous sentence, I mean to take the full range of indices, e.g. $\bigcup E_k$ stands for $\bigcup_{i=1}^{N}E_k$ in case we consider finitely many indices, or $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_k$ in case we consider infinitely many)

[edit: I've included a part at the bottom showing that the sets $E_k$ are disjoint]

---

Let's do the easy direction first. If $x\in \bigcup E_k$, then $x\in E_i$ for some $i$. By how $E_i$ is defined, then $x\in I_i$ as well, and therefore $x\in \bigcup I_k$. Hence $\bigcup E_k\subseteq \bigcup I_k$.

---

Now let's do the other direction. Suppose that $x\in \bigcup I_k$, then once again there is some $i$ such that $x\in I_i$, but naturally it may be possible that there are multiple $i$ for which this holds, since the sets $I_k$ do not have to be disjoint.

Let $X\subseteq\Bbb N$ be the set of natural numbers such that $x\in I_k$ if and only if $k\in X$. Since every subset of the natural numbers is [well-ordered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order), $X$ contains a least element, let's call it $i\in X$. Then $x\in I_i$, but for any $j<i$ we see that $x\notin I_j$ (otherwise $j$ would be in $X$, contradicting the minimality of $i$).

So, since $x\notin I_j$ for any $j<i$, also $x\notin \bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1} I_j
$. Hence $x\in I_i\setminus \bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1} I_j=E_i$. This shows that $\bigcup I_k\subseteq \bigcup E_k$.

---

What is left, is to show that the $E_k$ are disjoint from each other. Suppose $i\neq j$ are natural numbers, then $i<j$ or $j<i$. Let's assume the first, that $i<j$.

If $E_i\cap E_j\neq \varnothing$, then there is some $x$ such that both $x\in E_i=I_i\setminus \bigcup_{k=1}^{i-1} I_k$ and $x\in E_j=I_j\setminus \bigcup_{k=1}^{j-1}I_k$.

So $x\in I_i$ in particular. But since $i<j$, also $x\in \bigcup_{k=1}^{j-1}I_k=I_1\cup I_2\cup\cdots \cup I_i\cup\cdots I_{j-1}$. Which means that $x\notin E_j$, since $E_j$ is just $I_j$ without the elements from $\bigcup_{k=1}^{j-1}I_k$.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer! I’m a bit interested in how did you come up with the way to (it seems to create some kind of partiton) use $X \subseteq \Bbb N$ in order to get the contradiction?

Comment: @Georgi The more comments you give, the less I feel that you're ready to learn measure theory. What contradiction do you mean? I didn't use $X\subset\Bbb N$ to get a contradiction, $X$ is just the name I give to those indices of $I_k$ that contain some fixed $x$. Everything that I used this proof is basic manipulations on sets. Understanding the basics of sets (unions, intersections, complements, countable vs uncountable) is absolutely vital to understand measure theory. Through the questions that you ask, I can see that you lack this knowledge.